# Elixir equivalent of C#, Java, C++ enum

Tags: elixir

In C#, I might declare an enumeration like this:

```
enum QuestionType { Range, Text };
```

How would I do this in Elixir? What I would like to do is be able to pattern-match something like this:

```
def VerifyAnswer(QuestionType.range, answer) do
  assert answer >= 0 && answer <= 5
end
```

Or something like this, where `QuestionType.range` is a numeric constant, so it can be efficiently stored in DBs or serialized as an int to JSON.

Comment: Have you tried #elixir-lang on freenode? Even Jose Valim might answer a question asked there. Although it's good to see more Elixir questions here on SO.

Comment: Actually, asking questions in SO is very good because it can help others in the future. :) And I am frequently checking here too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use atoms where enums are used in other languages. For example, you could:

```
# use an atom-value tuple to mark the value '0..5' as a range
{ :range, 0..5 }

# group atoms together to represent a more involved enum
question = { :question, { :range, 0..5 }, { :text, "blah" } }

# use the position of an element to implicitly determine its type.
question = { :question, 0..5, "blah" }
```

You can use pattern matching here like so:

```
def verify_answer(question = { :question, range, text }, answer) do
  assert answer in range
end
```